# Split between two characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this url, Being passed into javascript. I have it like this at the moment

var Link = '<%= @car.link.split('&')[1]%>';
The link has `Id=63546&hjk`  I'm wanting to have the numbers only passed into the ticket.

So that 63546 is left. How would i go about this? It HAS to be between these two. Exactly `Id=` and `&`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this split needs to done in rails side or in javascript side,. On both the sides using regex the string can be splitted to get only the numbers

On ruby side

```
s ="Id=63546&hjk"
s[/\d+/].to_i
=> 63546
```

On Javascript side

```
var regex = /\d+/g;
var string = "Id=63546&hjk";
var matches = string.match(regex);
document.write(matches);
```

Comment: hi there, 

I'm doing the javascript side, I've got multiple numbers inside the url, not just that one and if i hover over matches in the debugger it shows all of them ordered 0-12, I'm wanting the 8th number, I think i'm being silly but i tries matches.8 and it didnt work. Ideas?

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to get the 8th digit from the matched result?. If so then `matches[0].split('')[7]`, should give you the 8th digit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and pull apart the uri with regular expressions I would use the functions the standard library and rails give you for manipulating these things:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_query(URI.parse(@car.link).query)['Id']
```

This parse the URI, extracts the query string, uses rack to turn it into a hash of key value pairs and then extracts the one named `Id`. It doesn't rely on Id being exactly a certain position in the Url or anything like that.